# SQL and SSRS Variable selection - hide some results from the end user

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a very simply SQL query

```
Select distinct title from agents 
 where 
title like '%Engineer%'
```

this renders a few results back, what I am looking to do is some how only SHOW the top 1 result to the users of there SRSS report as this will be a variable selection, but when selecting this single record it will include all of other results in the search.

so essentially all results will be hidden from the end user, but what they are actually doing is selecting all of the results returned from the above query.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is not really clear to me...

Comment: Are you trying to say that when the report is ran you only want to show the top 1 result as default value but when user selects other values then you want to show results as selection made by the user ???

Comment: So lets say I run the above query the results might render 

Support engineer
Engineer Support
Associate Support Engineer

There are 3 results shown there, I ONLY WANT to show the user the first result, but once they select this in the Report, it should automatically select the other results, this should be a transparent process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set a default value for the report parameter and create a stored procedure something like this

```
CREATE Proc usp_ReportProc
@Title NVARCHAR(30) = 'SomeDefaultValue'
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF @Title = 'SomeDefaultValue'
    BEGIN
        Select Top 1 title from agents 
     where title like '%Engineer%'
  END 
  ELSE 
   BEGIN
    Select distinct title from agents 
    where title IN (@Title)
  END 
END
```

Call this stored procedure from you report, When the report is ran initially it will pass the 'SomeDefaultValue' set by you in your report parameter and will return TOP 1 row, but when the user passes any different value it will show the results accordingly. you can further tweak the query to use the LIKE operator when user passes a parameter.